# CXF WADL missing details for complex objects

Tags: cxf, wadl

I have a CXF service (2.5.2) which consumes JSON object and produces JSON object like below

```
@POST
@Produces({"application/json"})
@Consumes({"application/json"})
public AResponseObject register(@PathParam("param1") String param1, User user) {
//
}
```

WADL generated by CXF for above service is as following:

```
<application xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<script id="tinyhippos-injected"/>
<grammars/>

<resources base="http://host/...">

<resource path="/register/{param1}">
<param name="param1" style="template" type="xs:string"/>
<method name="POST" id="register">
<request>
<representation mediaType="application/json"/>
</request>
<response>
<representation mediaType="application/json"/>
</response>
</method>
</resource>

</resources>
</application>
```

Above WADL file:-

1. doesn’t give any details for what User object is in grammars section
2. resource doesn’t specify that method requires a User object in request
   payload

How do I add these missing things to the WADL file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the cxf WadlGenerator as a provider in your Blueprint file:

```
<bean id="wadlGenerator" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.model.wadl.WadlGenerator">
    <property name="linkJsonToXmlSchema" value="true" />
</bean>

<jaxrs:server id="someRestService" address="/my/endpoint">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref component-id="someRestServiceBean" />
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref component-id="wadlGenerator" />
        <ref component-id="jsonProvider" />
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```